# JMS Queue receive causes application to crash

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

I've created a very simple JMS Queue example to send and receive messages. I have it set up to receive the messages after a certain number have been sent and then do work on them. After it receives all of the messages, trying to send more messages causes the application to crash.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.jms.*;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class JMSQueue {
    /** SLF4J logger. */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSQueue.class);

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/__defaultQueue")
    private Queue queue;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/__defaultQueueConnectionFactory")
    private QueueConnectionFactory factory;

    private int count = 0;

    private QueueConnection connection;
    private QueueSession session;
    private MessageProducer producer;
    private QueueReceiver receiver;

    public void init(){
        try {
            connection = factory.createQueueConnection();
            session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            receiver = session.createReceiver(queue);
            connection.start();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("JMS Queue Initialization failed.", e);
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage() throws JMSException {
        String messageBody = "ping" + count;
        Message request = session.createTextMessage(messageBody);
        request.setJMSReplyTo(queue);
        producer.send(request);
        count++;
        if (count >= 10) {
            count = 0;
            Message response = receiver.receive();
            while (response != null){
                String responseBody = ((TextMessage) response).getText();
                log.debug("jms - " + responseBody);
                try {
                    response = receiver.receive();
                } catch(JMSException e){
                    response = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run init once to create the connection, producer, and receiver, and then I run sendMessage 10 times. On the tenth time it spits out the output of all ten received messages. If I then hit sendMessage a couple of times after that, my application crashes. I have tried changing it to create and close the connection after each message which didn't change anything. I'm running a glassfish application web server and trying to use the queue to be notified of every rest call that users try to access.

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Nope, but while trying to get an error to display, I realized the problem. The receive hangs because there is no timeout for it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that the receive was hanging indefinitely due to there not being a timeout. Adding a timeout of 1 millisecond solved the issue.